# Can't rename SharePoint folder which contains files

Tags: 2010

I found strange SharePoint behavior.

I have document library "**LibraryTest**" with folder "**FolderTest**". User "**UserTest**" has **Contribute** permissions for library.

Scenario 1 (As **UserTest**):

- Folder "**FolderTest**" empty
- Rename folder "**FolderTest**" - **OK**

After that **SystemAccount** (for example) uploads new document "**TestDoc.docx**" to "**FolderTest**"

Scenario 2 (As **UserTest**):

- Has **Contribute** permissions for document "**TestDoc.docx**"
- Rename folder "**FolderTest**" - **OK**

Scenario 3 (As **UserTest**):

- Has **Read** permissions for document "**TestDoc.docx**" (**SystemAccount** broke role inheritance for document "**TestDoc.docx**" and provided **Read** permissions for **UserTest**)
- Rename folder "**FolderTest**" - **Access Denied**

Any ideas? By design?

Br,

Artur

Comment: so I'm having the same issue. I'm using SharePoint 2010. I have a folder with documents inside. When I attempt to change the folder name I get "Access Denied" with a Correlation ID:. I'm the SharePoint Admin for the whole document library. Can you not change the folder name if it has documents within?

Answer (score 1):

I think Sharepoint code does something like this:

1. Creates new folder
2. Moves files from old folder (checking permissions like 'Create' or 'Add');
3. And deletes old folder.

So, in that case your user (with 'Read' permission level) doesn't have enough privileges.

Answer (score 0):

We just have come across this too in SharePoint 2013. Basically all the content of such folder includes a path, which gets modified when renaming the folder. Thus, you need to have enough permissions to ALL content in the folder being renamed. No other OOB solution/workaround for this AFAIK, only code (rename the folder running elevated privileges).